# sinch calling app-to-phone why receiver getting calls from random numbers?

Tags: ios, iphone, sinch

I have verified number through sinch verification SDK. But the receiver getting calls from random numbers. As per my requirement if receiver saved my contact has to show saved name otherwise should show my number.
So please help me on this issue how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

With the Verification product that wont work, we set the callerid and its specific to each country to ensure high delivery

Comment: Hi cjensen,Can you look into below question "stackoverflow.com/questions/41482352/…”. Thanks –